# Hashing of password in banking mobile app

Tags: hash

Do I have to hash passwords on the client side of a banking mobile app since i am using a SSL network to send the password to the server end for hashing. Can the password be intercepted before transmission?

Comment: Hashing doesn't protect data in transit. That's not the threat it's trying to mitigate. Furthermore, banks have quite strict security requirements they have to follow, at least in the EU. Depending on where you are and want to operate, you may be subject to similar requirements.